# How to compare two DATE values based only on date part in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, compare, datepart

I am trying to get counts for last 30 days with the following query -

```
SELECT date_occured, COUNT(*) FROM problem
WHERE date_occured >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)
GROUP BY date_occured;

//date_occured field is of type DATE.
```

Basically, in my query I am trying to compare only the date part in the condition `date_occured >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)`, but it seems to compare the time too.

I tried the TRUNC as follows -

```
TRUNC(date_occured) >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30)
```

But when run the query it never returns.

I also tried -

```
SELECT date_occured, COUNT(*) FROM problem    
GROUP BY date_occured
HAVING TRUNC(date_occured) >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30);
```

Again it never returns.

How can I compare only the date parts from two DATE values in Oracle?

Comment: I imagine you need to group by `TRUNC(date_occured)` don't you?  i.e. you want a result per day, not per second.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*it never returns*"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this condition you only need to TRUNC the right-hand side:

```
WHERE date_occured >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30)
```

Why?  Because if TRUNC(date_occured) is later than TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30), then any moment in time after TRUNC(date_occured) is bound to be later than TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30) too.

It is obviously always true that date_occured >= TRUNC(date_occured) (think about it).

Logic says that if A >= B and B >= C then it follows that A >= C

Now substitute:

- A : date_occured
- B : TRUNC(date_occured)
- C : TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30)

Comment: I think the trunc() should also be applied to date_occured in order to ignore that time as well. Additionally I would use `trunc(current_date) - 30` instead

Comment: I am interested to know if this solves the issue.  I always assumed if you trunk a date with no time, it amounts to doing nothing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't think that makes any difference.  I would like to know if I am wrong on that with any references you have. Thanks.

Comment: @northopole: no, you are right it does not make a difference. I thought about a a `<=` condition where `trunc`ing date_occurred would have made a difference.

Comment: Ya, I am surprised this made any difference. Is the assumption here that the right side trunk will trunk both dates?  @Tony, can you provide an explanation?

Comment: @northpole: It only seems to logically solve the my problem. Is there a way if I really have to do this `TRUNC(date_occured) >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 30)`?

Comment: @BheshG, that is exactly why I would like an explanation from Tony.  Because if date_occured has a time, how would this then resolve?

Comment: @northpole: explanation added

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll want to trunc in the select part too:

```
 SELECT TRUNC(date_occured) AS short_date_occured, COUNT(*)
 FROM problem 
 WHERE date_occured >= trunc(SYSDATE- 30) 
 GROUP BY short_date_occured;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using SYSDATE vs CURRENT_DATE.  Sysdate uses the server's local time where CURRENT_DATE returns current date/time for the server in the client's connection's local time.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to suspect that Tony is correct and that you really only want to `TRUNC` the right-hand side of the expression.

If you do want to `TRUNC` both sides of the expression and you're encountering performance issues, you probably need a function based index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_problem_trunc_dt_occured
    ON problem( trunc( date_occurred ) );
```

That would allow your original query to use the function-based index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the index friendly approach.

you don't need to use functions on columns if you use Oracle's Native MONTHS_BETWEEN function.

It returns difference in number of months. Days are also given as difference but on the precision side that is why I preferred to use BETWEEN clause

```
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(date_occured, CURRENT_DATE - 30) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```