# compare date in sql command

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, date

My database save the date as this format `5/29/2015 12:07:58.000000 AM`. And I got the date input from user as `5/29/2015 12:07:58` format. Can I just compare the day/month/year instead of the whole line in sql command? my database is oracle and format as TIMESTAMP.
anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What database are you using and what is the data type of that column?  There should not be any format at all.  Format is only an issue when dealing with text and dates should be stored as binary dates, not text.  If you really do have a format then you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: oracle and timestamp

Comment: Do you prefer comparing individual day , month, year, or you mean the comparing date+month+year?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433363/how-to-compare-two-date-values-based-only-on-date-part-in-oracle.

Comment: yeap.. i would like to compare dd/mm/yyyy only @Jacky

Comment: Use `to_char()` or `to_date()`.

Answer (score 2):

> My database save the date as this format 5/29/2015 12:07:58.000000 AM

No. **Date/Timestamps** doesn't have any **format**. Oracle doesn't store the date/timestamps in the format you see. The format you see is only for **display** purpose. *Date is internally stored in 7 bytes which is Oracle's proprietary format*.

> Can I just compare the day/month/year instead of the whole line in sql command?

Of course you could. You could use **TRUNC** which truncates the time portion and leaves only date portion and data type remains as date.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) my_tmstmp FROM DUAL;

MY_TMSTMP
----------
2015-05-29
```

> And I got the date input from user as 5/29/2015 12:07:58 format.

So, you get the user input in that format as a **string**. You need to first **convert** it into DATE using **TO_DATE** and then compare it.

For example,

```
WHERE TRUNC(dt_column) < TO_DATE('05/29/2015 12:07:58', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

As I already said, if you want to ignore the time portion, then apply **TRUNC**.

However, applying **TRUNC** on the date **column** would suppress any regular **index** on that column. From performance point of view, better use a **Date range condition**.

For example,

```
WHERE dt_column
BETWEEN 
        TO_DATE('05/29/2015 12:07:58', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND     
        TO_DATE('05/29/2015 12:07:58', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') +1
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your record in databases and user input is both Timestamp.
You can use TRUNC function to get the date of this value and use this to compare

`declare
   v_tsdate  DATE;
   v_txdate  DATE;
begin
   v_tsdate := TRUNC( CAST('5/29/2015 12:07:58.000000 AM' as DATE) );
   v_txdate := TRUNC( CAST('5/29/2015 12:07:58' as DATE) );
   --do the comparision and conditions you need with v_tsdate and v_txdate
end;`

The reason I convert to DATE format, because `TRUNCT(Timestamp)` theoretically is `TRUNC(CAST(Timestamp AS DATE))`