# oracle pl/sql average from date difference

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to get the average from a date from this query

```
select service_id,t.arrival_date - 
       lag(t.arrival_date) over 
          (partition by t.service_id order by t.arrival_date) as arrival_date_diff
from table t
```

And I get this data as result

```
+000000000 00:37:00.000000
+000000000 00:23:30.000000
+000000000 00:07:04.000000
```

I tried to use

```
AVG(arrival_date_diff) to_date(round(avg(to_number(to_char(arrival_date_diff, 'J')))),'J')
```

How can I get the average from this date difference value and convert the average date to minutes?

Sample data:

```
04/06/18 08:57:34,000000
04/06/18 09:34:34,000000
04/06/18 09:34:34,000000
```

Expected result: average in minutes(for example: 8.5)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql

Comment: you can create a custom aggregate to do this for timestamps, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001583/need-to-find-average-processing-time-between-all-timestamp-records-in-oracle-sql/21003402#21003402)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract two DATE datatype values, result is number of **days**. For example (based on Scott's schema):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select deptno,
  2    hiredate,
  3    lag(hiredate) over (partition by deptno order by hiredate) lag_hiredate,
  4    --
  5    hiredate - lag(hiredate) over
  6               (partition by deptno order by hiredate) diff
  7  from emp
  8  order by deptno, hiredate;

    DEPTNO HIREDATE   LAG_HIREDA       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 09.06.1981
        10 17.11.1981 09.06.1981        161
        10 23.01.1982 17.11.1981         67
        20 17.12.1980
        20 02.04.1981 17.12.1980        106
        20 03.12.1981 02.04.1981        245
        30 20.02.1981
        30 22.02.1981 20.02.1981          2
        30 01.05.1981 22.02.1981         68
        30 08.09.1981 01.05.1981        130
        30 28.09.1981 08.09.1981         20
        30 03.12.1981 28.09.1981         66

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you want to select average difference, you'll have to use an inline view or CTE as AVG and analytic function can't be used at the same time, i.e. `avg(lag(...))`.

Finally, as you need number of minutes, multiply the result (days, right?) by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day) and 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour):

```
SQL> with inter as
  2    (select deptno,
  3            hiredate - lag(hiredate) over
  4                       (partition by deptno order by hiredate) diff
  5     from emp
  6  )
  7  select deptno,
  8    avg(diff) avg_diff_days,
  9    --
 10    avg(diff) * (24 * 60) minutes
 11  from inter
 12  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO AVG_DIFF_DAYS    MINUTES
---------- ------------- ----------
        10           114     164160
        20         175,5     252720
        30          57,2      82368

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: added *timestamp* example]**

```
SQL> create table test (datum timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> select * From test;

DATUM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04.06.18 08:57:34,000000
04.06.18 09:34:34,000000
04.06.18 09:34:34,000000

SQL>
SQL> select datum - lag(datum) over (order by datum) diff
  2  from test;

DIFF
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

+000000000 00:37:00.000000
+000000000 00:00:00.000000

SQL> -- cast timestamps to dates first, then subtract them; for the final result,
SQL> -- multiply number of days by 24 hours (in a day) and 60 minutes (in an hour)
SQL> select avg(diff) * 24 * 60 avg_minutes
  2  from (select cast(datum as date) - cast(lag(datum) over (order by datum) as date) diff
  3        from test
  4       );

AVG_MINUTES
-----------
       18,5

SQL>
```

Comment: I get the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`

Comment: It looks like OP is getting an `interval` back. I'm guessing their `arrival_date` field is a timestamp, not a date, in which case they'll have to [convert it to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559741/convert-timestamp-to-date-in-oracle-sql) before this will work.

Comment: Right; thank you for the comment and useful link for Joseleg, @kfinity. Scott doesn't have any *timestamps* so I used what I had.